# Kendo grid row disapeared when editing after adding a row

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I defined a kendo grid like that, and somehow after adding a row, the first edit click I do (before sending to the server) the row I just added is disappearing, and after refreshing its still there.
any suggestions why its happening?

```
$("#actionGrid").kendoGrid({          
    scrollable: true,
    height: "200px",
    toolbar: [{name: "create", text: "Add"}],
    editable: {
        mode: "inline",
        confirmation: false
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "order", title: "Order", width: 80 },
        { field: "action", title: "Action name"},           
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], width: 100 }                       
    ],
    dataSource: {
        schema: {
            model: {
                id:"taskId",
                    fields: {
                        taskId: { type:"number" },
                        order: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0 } },                          
                        action: {}
                    }
                }
            },
         transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "action/readByPId?pId=" + pId
                },
                destroy: {
                    dataType:"json",
                    type:"POST",
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    url: "action/delete"
                },
                update: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "action/update"
                },
                create: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "action/update"
                },                                     
                parameterMap:function parameterMap(options,type) { 
                    if(type !== "read"){        
                        return JSON.stringify(options);
                    }
                }
            },
         sort: { field: "order", dir: "asc" }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Kendo Grid have straight rules .Like whenever create new record ,have to return updated list to client side call . please make sure whether that updated record is returning or not.

IF you doing online offline feature of kendo UI . then follow this following demo. 
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/offline

you have not mentioned the data communication method . but if you are doing purly custom way then you have to update datasoure after doing any operation .Please put following code to get update with new data .

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read(); <!--  first reload data source -->

$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh(); <!--  refresh current UI -->
```

Comment: Like you Click on Add button > Then Fill the data > Insted of Save you click on Edit on another record . right ?

Comment: Yes, I am returning the new record and the grid is updated,
My grid is in a dialog and after creating a record, the first click on the edit command button is disappearing the new row from the grid's view, but when closing the dialog and opening it again the record is still there and then the edit is working fine only after clicking on it 3 times in a row..
and my data communication methods are not custom.

Comment: your issue is truely awkward. I m really excited to see in UI like gif or in fildller if possible .

Comment: How can I send it to u?

Comment: yes . I am . but your given code is not enough to understand your issue .

Comment: How can I send u the gif of the issue that I took?

Comment: Edit your question and use fiddler or GIF or github